# How to show my iPhone app listed in iPhone's native Photos app share menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, file-sharing, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I want to install my iOS application in my iPhone's native photos app share menu list like facebook, twitter etc..Please give me the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow! Any code you've tried? It's easier to get the answer that you are looking for if you provide some code as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Extensions to show your app while sharing in default apps like FB and twitter.

https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/